# Need explanation of jquery code regarding slideshow

Tags: jquery

a div has few image and the code below is showing one image at a time. it is just like slide show. i read the code but just do not understand how it is working. the code is tested and it is working. only one problem found that sometime animation run so fast. i just do not understand what is wrong in the code as a reason sometime images changes very fast in slide show.

### here is html and jquery code

```
<div class="headerCarouselwrapper">
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image1.jpg" />
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image2.jpg" />
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image3.jpg" />
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image4.jpg" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.headerCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('img').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper');
    }, 5000);
});
```

**two things i need to know**

1)how this code works. if possible then tell me how each like works

2) why sometime slide show animation run very fast.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The code is wrapped within a "ready" handler. The anonymous function bind to the "ready" event is execute once the DOM is loaded (the "load" event fires when all assets in a page are loaded - html, images, js, css...)

   ```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        // executes when the DOM is ready
    });
   ```

   [jQuery ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
2. Hide all images except the first one:

   ```
   $('.headerCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
   ```

   The pseudo selector allows matching elements with an index greater-then then one specified. `.headerCarouselwrapper img` finds all images in container and `:gt(0)` filters to have all except the first one.

   [:gt() selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)
3. Every 5 seconds, execute a function:

   ```
   setInterval(function () {
       // executes every 5000 milliseconds
   }, 5000);
   ```

   [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)
4. In the anonymous function executed every 5sec, takahe the first child of the container with class `.headerCarouselwrapper` (basically the visible image) and fade it out, get the next image with .next() and fade it in. Append the image that was faded out to the container to it cycles:

   ```
   // get first child in ".headerCarouselwrapper" which is the currently
   // visible image and fade it out
   $('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
   // get the next <IMG> and fade it in
   .next('img').fadeIn()
   // get back the image that was faded out
   // and append it (move it) at the end of the container
   // so the slideshow cycle
   .end().appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper');
   ```

   [.end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/)
    [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

---

**About the problem of the *fast* animation**

As you told in the comment, you are using jquery 1.6.2.

jQuery 1.6 introduced support for the API `requestAnimationFrame` (supported in FF and Chrome, but not IE I think). It has revealed to be problematic:

> No more animation “worm holes”: We had high hopes for the browser’s
>   requestAnimationFrame API when we added support into version 1.6.
>   However, one of the highest-volume complaints we’ve received since
>   then relates to **the way requestAnimationFrame acts when a tab is not
>   visible. All the animations initiated when the tab is invisible
>   “stack” and are not executed until the tab is brought back into focus.
>   Then they all animate at warp speed!** We’ve removed support for this
>   API (which has no impact on the way you call jQuery’s animation
>   features) and plan to incorporate it into a future version of jQuery.

You should upgrade your jquery version to at least 1.6.3.

[Source](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/08/29/jquery-1-6-3-rc1-released/)

Comment: the most important issue why some time animation run very fast. i mean images is changing very fast.is there any problem in the code.here is url have look at the problem.http://demo.langarth.com/bba/partsbase_your_rebuild_order_3.php
open my site and another any site in firefox in two different tab. just stick with other for few minute say 2 or 3 minute and then come back to my site and then u can see that slide show running very fast and again gets normal. i think .end() function is making problem. how to fix it any idea?

Comment: .appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')
it seems that image is getting append at the last in the div which has style "headerCarouselwrapper" .
i have confusion here all the images are there in the div which is attached with headerCarouselwrapper style.
if all the images are there in the div then why should i again append the same images in the div with the code like
.appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')

Comment: For the last comment: the .appendTo() is used to provide a cycling effect. .end() returns the initial seletion (".headerCarouselwrapper :first-child") which is the first image, that is now hidden. .appendTo() will **move it at the end**. So you the slideshow is cycling.

Comment: For the first comment: which version of jquery ? does it happend in Chrome or IE ?

Comment: yes it happen in Chrome and FF but code run smoothly in IE. jquery version is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js . i think there is glitch in code it self and that is why sometime animation is getting. please go to the site and see ur self http://demo.langarth.com/bba/partsbase_your_rebuild_order_3.php . u just open my site in one tab and another site in other tab. first stick with other site tab for few minute and then come back to my site and then u can see slide animation is running so fast for few second. after some time it will be automatically normal.

Comment: as if something was stored in stack or queue and show images from the queue so fast just to clear it when some one come back to my site tab after few minute. it is not happening all the time. it happens only when user open two site like my one and other one side by side in two tab but seeing other site for some time and when user come back to my site after some time then he looks slide show animation run so fast. i think something wrong in the code. please help.

Comment: It's a known problem with 1.6.2. I've updated my answer with explanation.

Comment: can anyone tell me that the first child is already in div having class called headerCarouselwrapper  then what is need to again append the first-child into headerCarouselwrapper div like appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper') ? please explain in detail. thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7235/discussion-between-thomas-and-didier-ghys)

Answer (score 1):

**What it does**

`$(document).ready` - Binds an event handler to the `ready` event, which fires when the DOM is ready for manipulation. See [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

`$('.headerCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide()` - Hides all elements that match the selector. In this case, it selects all images (apart from the first one) that are descendants of elements with the class "headerCarouselwrapper". See [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).

`setInterval` - Repeats something at a given interval. The interval given in this case is 5000ms (5 seconds). The anonymous function passed as the first argument is what gets repeated. See [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) on MDN.

`$('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()` - Fade out the first child of every element with the class "headerCarouselwrapper". See [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

`.next('img').fadeIn()` - Fade in the immediately following sibling element (if it's an `img` element). See [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

`.end()` - Return the currently selected element from the sibling to the original `:first-child`. See [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).

`.appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')` - Append the currently selected elements to any elements with a class of "headerCarouselwrapper". See [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

*You could have worked most of that out for yourself by looking at the jQuery documentation.*

Comment: the most important issue why some time animation run very fast. i mean images is changing very fast.is there any problem in the code.here is url have look at the problem.http://demo.langarth.com/bba/partsbase_your_rebuild_order_3.php
open my site and another any site in firefox in two different tab. just stick with other for few minute say 2 or 3 minute and then come back to my site and then u can see that slide show running very fast and again gets normal. i think .end() function is making problem. how to fix it any idea?

Comment: .appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')
it seems that image is getting append at the last in the div which has style "headerCarouselwrapper" .
i have confusion here all the images are there in the div which is attached with headerCarouselwrapper style.
if all the images are there in the div then why should i again append the same images in the div with the code like
.appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')

Comment: can anyone tell me that the first child is already in div having class called headerCarouselwrapper  then what is need to again append the first-child into headerCarouselwrapper div like appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper') ? please explain in detail. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () { // waits util the page has fully loaded before initialising
$('.headerCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide(); // hide every image except for the first
    setInterval(function () { // call the following code every 5 seconds
        $('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut() // hide the first image
        .next('img') // select the next image
        .fadeIn() // fade this in
        .end() // end the previous selection ... i.e. go back to the first image again
        .appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper'); // append to the wrapper, i.e. move it to the end of the list of images
    }, 5000);
});
```

I would guess the weird timing issues are something to do with the fadeIn() and fadeOut(). They both set up their own timeout loops and as javscript [queues up timeouts and intervals internally](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) this could be interfering with the main interval's execution.

Comment: the most important issue why some time animation run very fast. i mean images is changing very fast.is there any problem in the code.here is url have look at the problem.http://demo.langarth.com/bba/partsbase_your_rebuild_order_3.php
open my site and another any site in firefox in two different tab. just stick with other for few minute say 2 or 3 minute and then come back to my site and then u can see that slide show running very fast and again gets normal. i think .end() function is making problem. how to fix it any idea?

Comment: .appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')
it seems that image is getting append at the last in the div which has style "headerCarouselwrapper" .
i have confusion here all the images are there in the div which is attached with headerCarouselwrapper style.
if all the images are there in the div then why should i again append the same images in the div with the code like
.appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper')

Comment: can anyone tell me that the first child is already in div having class called headerCarouselwrapper  then what is need to again append the first-child into headerCarouselwrapper div like appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper') ? please explain in detail. thanks

Comment: when you append an item into a collection it's already a member of the item is moved to the end of the collection. This only happens with DOM collections (i.e. doesn't apply to arrays).